# Detecting an ArcGIS Split Rule / Ratio Policy

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have two identical layers in ArcGIS Desktop, one of them with two numeric fields that have a Ratio Policy applied to them.

Is there any way in ArcGIS Desktop to identify a field [or a set of fields] in a layer with a Ratio Policy?

If I get an ArcMap Document with these two layers, how would I know which layer has a field with Ratio Policy?

Comment: Did you find anything or nothing in the ArcGIS Online Help on "split rule ratio policy"?  Either way can you **edit** that information into your question to save us simply repeating your research, please?

Comment: I suspect that the two layers are not actually identical. One is probably a graphic layer (the normal type of layer created by just 'adding' data), and the other is likely a Feature Layer, created by the Make Feature Layer tool. A Feature layer allows additional capabilities over graphic layers (Ratio Policy being one of them, but also note you generally can't perform operations directly on a dataset in ModelBuilder - you must first make a Feature Layer out of it). I am unaware of and was unable to find any quick/definitive way to tell the difference between types in an mxd.

Comment: @ChrisW Thank you for your reply. It seems there is no quick way to find the difference in a Map Document. The point on the differences between Graphic Layers and Feature Layers was well put and very important distinction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way in ArcGIS Desktop to identify a field [or a set of field] in a layer with ratio policy?

**Yes, split/merge policies are set with field domains in ArcGIS.** to identify a field with split policy, you should right click on a layer and check its fields one by one to see whether a domain is set for the field. if there is one, go to Subtypes tab of the feature class and click the domain button and navigate to the domain name to see if there is any split policy is set for the domain. (see the screenshot)

[image: Featureclass Field with domain]

[image: Split policies]

> If I get an ArcMap Document with these two layers , How would I know which layer has a field with ratio policy?

**Follow my answer to the first question.**

Update:
Based on Chris W comment and another [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107933/set-a-split-policy-rule-on-a-field-without-domain-in-arcmap) again answered by Chris:

> This answer refers to the Split Policy set with a Domain, in which
>   case the policy is actually part of the data. Geoprocessing tools do
>   not honor any settings made in this fashion. However a Ratio Policy
>   can be set when creating a Feature Layer. This is a property of the
>   layer and not the data

However to find out whether there is a split rule applied to a field in a featurelayer you should use arcpy (I couldn't find a way in Arcmap to see whether a field in a Feature layer has a split rule).

In Python you should loop through  your layers and describe each layer and use `getSplitRule(index)` method .

Sample Code:

```
import arcpy

feature_class = "c:/Data/wells.shp"
layer = "temp_layer"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(feature_class, layer)

# Create a describe object
desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)

# If a feature layer, continue
if desc.dataType == "FeatureLayer":

    # Create a fieldinfo object
    field_info = desc.fieldInfo
    for index in xrange(0, field_info.count):
        spRule = field_info.getSplitRule (index)
        print index,spRule #spRule can be RATION or NONE
```

Comment: This answer refers to the [Split Policy set with a Domain](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001s00000001000000), in which case the policy is actually part of the data. Geoprocessing tools do not honor any settings made in this fashion. However a Ratio Policy can be set when creating a [Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000). This is a property of the *layer* and not the data. It cannot be identified in the same way, if at all.