# Automatic numbering when split the polygon in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

Can anyone help me when I split the polygon the number should be automatically update in the attribute table to the second polygon?

Example : I have the polygon name called 5 in attribute table, when I split the polygon the divided second polygon name In attribute table should be update as 5-1 or 5_1 something like this.

Comment: You could duplicate the ID by setting the [split policy](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107933/set-a-split-policy-rule-on-a-field-without-domain-in-arcmap) of the attribute domain. Adding some incremental number would require some sort of bespoke development.